# How to avoid cyclic dependency when using MapStruct and converting collections (List)?

Tags: java, mapstruct

- entities:

  - AbstractEntity

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity<ID extends Serializable> implements Persistable<ID> {

    private ID id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Override
    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        return null == getId();
    }

   
}
```

- Mesh

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mesh")
public class Mesh extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    private String name;

    private int comSize;

    private List<MeshColumn> columns;
    private List<MeshLine> lines;


    @Column(name = "com_size")
    public int getComSize() {
        return сomSize;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mesh")
    public List<MeshColumn> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mesh")
    public List<MeshLine> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

   ...
}
```

- MeshColumn

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mesh_column")
public class MeshColumn extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

   private int number;

   private Mesh mesh;


   @JoinColumn(name = "mesh_id")
   public Mesh getMesh() {
       return mesh;
   }
...

}
```

- MeshLine

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mesh_line")
public class MeshLine extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    private int number;

    private Mesh mesh;

    @JoinColumn(name = "mesh_id")
    public Mesh getMesh() {
        return mesh;
    }
...

}
```

- dto

```java
public class MeshDto {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private int comSize;

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<MeshColumn> columns;

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<MeshLine> lines;



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MeshDto meshDto = (MeshDto) o;
        return cellSize == meshDto.cellSize &&
                Objects.equals(id, meshDto.id) &&
                Objects.equals(name, meshDto.name);
    }

}
```

- mapper

To avoid looping (included in MapStruct):

```java
@Component
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {

    private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();

    @BeforeMapping
    public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {

        T t = (T) knownInstances.get(source);
        return t;
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
        knownInstances.put( source, target );
    }
}
```

!!! Only it doesn't work if there is a transformation of **List-entity**   to **List-Dto**

- common

```java
public interface CommonMapperForCycleAvoiding<D, E>  {

    D toDto(E e, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    E toEntity(D d, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    List<D> toListDto(List<E> entityList, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
  
    List<E> toListEntity(List<D> dtoList, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
}
```

- meshMapper

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MeshMapper extends CommonMapperForCycleAvoiding <MeshDto, Mesh> {
}
```

- Transformer method

```java
    private List<MeshDto> toListDto(List<Mesh> list) {
        return meshMapper.toListDto(list, this.cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
    }
```

```sql
create table mesh
(
    id        bigserial not null
        constraint mesh_pkey
            primary key,
    cell_size integer,
    name      varchar(255)
);


create table mesh_column
(
    id      bigserial not null
        constraint mesh_column_pkey
            primary key,
    number  integer   not null,
    mesh_id bigint
        constraint fk1
            references mesh
);


create table mesh_line
(
    id      bigserial not null
        constraint mesh_line_pkey
            primary key,
    number  integer   not null,
    mesh_id bigint
        constraint fk4
            references mesh
);

create table mesh_cell
(
    mesh_column_id bigint not null
        constraint mesh_cell_mesh_column_id_fkey
            references mesh_column,
    mesh_line_id   bigint not null
        constraint mesh_cell_mesh_line_id_fkey
            references mesh_line,
    value          text   not null,
    constraint mesh_cell_pkey
        primary key (mesh_column_id, mesh_line_id)
);
```

### Update

```java
@Component
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {

    private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new HashMap<>();

   .....
}
```

This also won't solve the problem

```java
package com.persistable.persistable.service.mapper;

import com.persistable.persistable.domain.Mesh;
import com.persistable.persistable.domain.MeshColumn;
import com.persistable.persistable.domain.MeshLine;
import com.persistable.persistable.service.dto.MeshDto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-7.3.2.jar, environment: Java 11.0.9.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
@Component
public class MeshMapperImpl implements MeshMapper {

    @Override
    public MeshDto toDto(Mesh e, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {
        MeshDto target = context.getMappedInstance( e, MeshDto.class );
        if ( target != null ) {
            return target;
        }

        if ( e == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        MeshDto meshDto = new MeshDto();

        context.storeMappedInstance( e, meshDto );

        meshDto.setId( e.getId() );
        meshDto.setName( e.getName() );
        meshDto.setCellSize( e.getCellSize() );
        List<MeshColumn> list = e.getColumns();
        if ( list != null ) {
            meshDto.setColumns( new ArrayList<MeshColumn>( list ) );
        }
        List<MeshLine> list1 = e.getRows();
        if ( list1 != null ) {
            meshDto.setRows( new ArrayList<MeshLine>( list1 ) );
        }

        return meshDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Mesh toEntity(MeshDto d, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {
        Mesh target = context.getMappedInstance( d, Mesh.class );
        if ( target != null ) {
            return target;
        }

        if ( d == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        context.storeMappedInstance( d, mesh );

        mesh.setId( d.getId() );
        mesh.setName( d.getName() );
        mesh.setCellSize( d.getCellSize() );
        List<MeshColumn> list = d.getColumns();
        if ( list != null ) {
            mesh.setColumns( new ArrayList<MeshColumn>( list ) );
        }
        List<MeshLine> list1 = d.getRows();
        if ( list1 != null ) {
            mesh.setRows( new ArrayList<MeshLine>( list1 ) );
        }

        return mesh;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MeshDto> toListDto(List<Mesh> entityList, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {
        List<MeshDto> target = context.getMappedInstance( entityList, List.class );
        if ( target != null ) {
            return target;
        }

        if ( entityList == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<MeshDto> list = new ArrayList<MeshDto>( entityList.size() );
        context.storeMappedInstance( entityList, list );

        for ( Mesh mesh : entityList ) {
            list.add( toDto( mesh, context ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Mesh> toListEntity(List<MeshDto> dtoList, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {
        List<Mesh> target = context.getMappedInstance( dtoList, List.class );
        if ( target != null ) {
            return target;
        }

        if ( dtoList == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Mesh> list = new ArrayList<Mesh>( dtoList.size() );
        context.storeMappedInstance( dtoList, list );

        for ( MeshDto meshDto : dtoList ) {
            list.add( toEntity( meshDto, context ) );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I could use **@JsonIgnore**, but in this case I would like to see nested associations as well, but not in recursion

here is what is generated

Unfortunately, this only works for single transformations.

But if I use a collection, I still get looping.  How can this be fixed ?

Can anyone have any idea what the problem is here and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe try this https://hellokoding.com/handling-circular-reference-of-jpa-hibernate-bidirectional-entity-relationships-with-jackson-jsonignoreproperties/

Comment: This is interesting, but there we are talking about serialization of data that is sent to the client, I also showed an example of transformation from entity to dto. The article that you indicated is a little different, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

#### Analysis

I've done a test with your example (adding the missing getters/setters) and the result for me with MapStruct `1.4.2.Final` and `1.5.0.Beta2` is that the functionality works.
There is no infinite recursion with passing in a collection of size 2.

Below is the test that I have used for this:

```
    @Test
    void recursionTest() {
        MeshMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper( MeshMapper.class );

        Mesh mesh1 = new Mesh();
        MeshColumn meshColumn1_1 = new MeshColumn();
        meshColumn1_1.setMesh( mesh1 );
        Mesh mesh2 = new Mesh();
        MeshColumn meshColumn1_2 = new MeshColumn();
        meshColumn1_2.setMesh( mesh2 );
        mesh1.setColumns( List.of( meshColumn1_1, meshColumn1_2 ) );
        MeshColumn meshColumn2 = new MeshColumn();
        meshColumn2.setMesh( mesh1 );
        mesh2.setColumns( List.of( meshColumn2 ) );

        List<MeshDto> listDto = mapper.toListDto( List.of( mesh1, mesh2 ), new CycleAvoidingMappingContext() );
        List<Mesh> listMesh = mapper.toListEntity( listDto, new CycleAvoidingMappingContext() );

        // prints out '2' and '1'. which is correct because mesh1 has 2 columns, and mesh2 has 1 column.
        listMesh.stream().map( mesh -> mesh.getColumns().size() ).forEach( System.out::println );
    }
```

#### Possible solution

One option that comes to mind is that your persistence layer is returning new objects every time. Since you are using an `IdentityHashMap`, the source must be the same object, and not equal to it. If you would change this into a normal `HashMap` and the equals are based on `Id`, then that might fix the problem.

For example: comparing `Mesh#1@123456` and `Mesh#1@654321` on being the same object would return `false`, while comparing `Mesh#1@123456` and `Mesh#1@654321` on being equal to each other would return `true`.

#### Possible solution using a key instead of the source object in the hashmap.

```
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {

    private Map<Key, Object> knownInstances = new HashMap<Key, Object>();

    @Override
    @BeforeMapping
    public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {

        T t = (T) knownInstances.get( toKey( source ) );
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
        knownInstances.put( toKey( source ), target );
    }

    private Key toKey(Object source) {
        if ( source instanceof AbstractEntity ) {
            Serializable id = ( (AbstractEntity<?>) source ).getId();
            return new Key( source, id );
        }
        return new Key( source, null );
    }

    private class Key {
        private Object source;
        private Serializable id;

        public Key(Object source, Serializable id) {
            this.source = source;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash( source, id );
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (id != null) {
                return Objects.equals( id, ( (Key) obj ).id )
                    && Objects.equals( source.getClass(), ( (Key) obj ).source.getClass() );
            }else {
                if ( ( (Key) obj ).id != null ) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return Objects.equals( source.getClass(), ( (Key) obj ).source.getClass() );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this, you can find the test and source code I used here:

Root issue folder: https://github.com/Zegveld/mapstruct-sandbox/tree/main/infiniteMapping/eu.helral.mapstruct.sandbox.infiniteMapping

The `MeshMapperTest` contains 3 tests:

- A test showing that it would normally work.
- A test showing that an infinite recursion variant does not work.
- A test showing a solution for the infinite recursion variant.

The `FixedCycleAvoidingMappingContext` extends the `CycleAvoidingMappingContext` so that I did not have to duplicate the entire mapper as well for testing the fix.

## Solution

Create more DTO objects.

Currently you have the following input structure:

`Mesh` --> `MeshColumn` --> `Mesh`

You transform this into:

`MeshDto` --> `MeshColumn` --> `Mesh`

What you want is:

`MeshDto` --> `MeshColumnDto` --> `MeshDto`

So what you need to do is also create a `MeshColumnDto`, `MeshLineDto`, or exclude these from the mapping.

available since 1.5.0.Beta's:
Continuing on nested evaluations, you might even want to change the cyclic preventer into a @Condition method for all Mesh mappings, so that when you are about to map the same object it instead skips it.
See https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#conditional-mapping for more information.

Comment: You have a synthetic test. But I tried on a real base. And there's still a cycle.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion 'replacing the `IdentityHashMap` with a `HashMap`' that I made for fixing it?

Comment: A tried to do it, if I understood you correctly. But you do understand that the @OneToMany links and the like (that is, the variables that store them) should not participate in the redefinition of equals and hashCode

Comment: Hmmm I just did some more testing and created an example class where I've used an hashmap and a key-object to prevent an infinite cycle. I'll update my answer above with the example of this. Hopefully that might work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried to make the class that you suggested and tried to replace it with it. But I get an error ...token(Object)' in 'com.persistable.persistable.service.mapper.FixedCycleAvoidingMappingContext' clashes with 'toKey(Object)' in 'com.persistable.persistable.service.mapper.CycleAvoidingMappingContext'; attempting to use incompatible return type. I can't figure out how to use your solution in relation to my example.

Comment: https://github.com/alex-sky-cloud/persistable-use-in-postgresql.git  The cycle still remained. You can see an example

Comment: The error was my mistake, I forgot to make the toKey method private. It should work when it is private, I'll see if I also get that cycle error in your example, because the tests inside the repository you supplied are succeeding when I use a h2 database.  So I'll be installing a postgresdb for testing with your actual settings, but this might take me a while. (updating the answer to reflect the private method.)

Edit: debugged, with my h2 db the db has no content. need to fill it to test. doing that will get back to you.

Comment: I have tried several routes, but no luck in getting the infinite loop working on my end. :(
After creating a local postgresdb with the correct schema's and using the supplied sql content your example runs locally without getting to a StackOverflowError.
It seems that the level 1 cache that Hibernate uses prevents the infinite loop for me, and I have not found a way to disable this using spring boot. (Did find a way to disable the L2 cache, but that is not used in this case)

Comment: I updated the question and you can see the recursion. In addition, the Hibernate cache first level does not play any role here.  The transformer should cut it off.  Of course, when we try to look at associations in the Debug mode in the transactional method, then until the tarnaction is closed and the Persistent context is open, we will endlessly go deep into the associations. in addition, I set ---- open-in-view: false-----, so at the time of receiving the Rest data, Persistent context should be closed

Comment: level 1 cache that Hibernate will not be able to prevent an infinite loop in any way, since all this is done in one Hibernate session, and the cache of the first level works within this session. For a second-level cache in Hibernate, you need an explicitly configured provider. I don't use that

Comment: Ahh with your output of the cyclic I see what is going wrong. I'll update my answer to reflect this. In short you do not have enough DTO objects.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your issue, I've added a new answer that should answer your original issue. 
I originally thought you had a problem with that MapStruct kept mapping items and threw an StackOverflowError, but instead your issue is that you wanted to map until you get to the same item and then cut off the hierarchy instead of reusing the previously mapped item.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem description

What you want to prevent is:
MeshDto#1 --> MeshColumnDto#2 --> MeshDto#1 --> MeshColumnDto#2 etc cyclic referencing.

## Solution

To prevent cyclic references you need to create an endpoint object to return instead of the actual object. Currently mapstruct just returns what it previously converted, but instead what you want is perhaps just the id of the item and no more information.

One option to achieve this is the following:

1. add an interface to all your Dto's which has a method to create an endpoint object.
2. whenever you find an already converted object, replace it with the endpoint object.

Example base interface:

```
interface BaseDto<SELF> {
    <SELF> createEndPointCopy();
}
```

example implementation:

```
MeshDto implements BaseDto<MeshDto> {
  // default stuff.
  @Override
  MeshDto createEndPointCopy() {
    MeshDto endpoint = new MeshDto();
    endpoint.setId(id);
    return endpoint;
  }
}
```

Next create the HierarchyEndingMappingContext

```
@Component
public class HierarchyEndingMappingContext {

    private Collection<Object, BaseDto<?>> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, BaseDto<?>>();

    @BeforeMapping
    public <T extends BaseDto> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        T t = (T) knownInstances.get(source);
        return t != null ? t.createEndPointCopy() : null;
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget BaseDto target) {
        knownInstances.put( source, target );
    }
}
```

You might need to do some tweaking to have it respect hierarchies, because currently it will cause the following side effect when mapping a collection:
(A, B, C are instances, so A knows B, B knows C, and C knows B)
if I map collection `[A{B{C{B}}}, C{B}]`

we get as result: `[A{B{C{EndpointObject<B>}}}, EndpointObject<C>]`

while you might want to get: `[A{B{C{EndpointObject<B>}}}, C{B{EndpointObject<C>}}]`

## Important

All objects need to be mapped to be able to use this solution. So if you only have a MeshDto, but no MeshColumnDto then it will not work. You will need to have MeshDto refer to MeshColumnDto instead of MeshColumn, because otherwise you would just inherit the same MeshColumn object instead of one with the hierarchy cut off.

## Example repository

I've added an example in the `remove.recursion` package of the following project: https://github.com/Zegveld/mapstruct-sandbox/tree/main/infiniteMapping/eu.helral.mapstruct.sandbox.infiniteMapping
There is also a test there that I used to confirm that it does indeed block the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/r-uu/sandbox.mapstruct.aroundmapping) is a working example including tests and documented code that covers how to map bidirectionally related DTO and Entity types (departments with sets of employees) without running into stack overflow because of cyclic dependencies. It leverages mapstruct callbacks (`@org.mapstruct.BeforeMapping`, `@org.mapstruct.AfterMapping`) and a `@org.mapstruct.Context`. Additionally it shows how to encapsulate the sets of employees from direct client access to provide correctness of bidirectional relation. The example leverages mapstruct together with lombok. The example is pretty minimal and I hope it is at least inspirational.